# Why is my kitten’s tail tip like that?

Tags: cats, health

[image: tip of tail]

Today I noticed my kitten’s tail looking like this, completely stumped as to how this could’ve happened, and can’t find anything on this online.
Currently I have two theories:

She does play with her tail from time to time, and might have played to roughly? Or over cleaned her tail?

The day I spotted this there was an incident where she was laying on the low heat radiator and heard her growl. I checked on her immediately but there didn’t seem to be an issue, but I’m thinking maybe her tail fell in where it’s warmer and got singed?

Side note: we just got her a little under a month ago and in that time she’s had worm medicine, and ear mite medicine as she had an issue in her ear (turned out to be an infected wound) and had to wear a cone for 2 weeks.

Comment: Can you tell if part of the tail is gone, as in, do you feel rough skin or a scab? Or is it just the fur? If the fur is singed, the remaining hair would be “crunchy”. Does she act hurt if you touch the tail?

Comment: It’s hard to tell as it’s mostly just fur I see. It’s soft to touch and she’s very unbothered if I touch it.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! Please take the [tour], it only takes a minute. This is not a discussion forum, therefore the answer function is reserved to actually answering your question. If you have new information, please [edit] your question so that it contains all information. If you want to answer to a comment without adding anything to your question, please do so in a comment, not in an answer.

Answer (score 2):

The best answer I know for strange phenomenon in animals is to ask the vet. You mention that you just got her and that you have already had health issues with her, i.e. ear mites and worms. Did this kitty come from a feral mother and never have a physical examination by a vet? If so, it's time for a full examination and all the shots.

If her tail looked fully furred until today, it is possible that there are tiny mites in there, making it itchy so that she chewed off the hair. Though it's rather amazing that she trimmed it so evenly. Maybe she has some kind of problem that makes the long outer hairs fall off while keeping the fine inner coat.

Time to see the vet.